# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getData' with a while loop, is not prevented?

Tags: python, search, linked-list

I am writing code that goes through a linked list and searches it for a given list of values and returns where it is located. This is the code:

```
def bruteForce(aList, data):
    index = 0
    curr = aList.getHead()
    while(curr.getNext() != None):
        if(curr.getData() == data[0]):
            match = 0
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if(curr.getData() == data[i]):
                    match += 1
                if(match == len(data)):
                    print("Found a match at " + str(index) + "!")
                curr = curr.getNext()
                index += 1
        curr = curr.getNext()
        index += 1
```

This is how I call it:

```
file11 = input("What are we searching for today in file 1? ")
file12 = input("What else are we searching for today in file 1? ")
print("Now searching using Brute Force!")
startBF = time.time()
bruteForce(ickleList, file11)
bruteForce(ickleList, file12)
endBF = time.time()
bruteForceTime = endBF - startBF
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Find It Fast.py", line 251, in <module>
    bruteForce(ickleList, file12)
  File "Find It Fast.py", line 147, in bruteForce
    if(curr.getData() == data[i]):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getData'
```

My `while` loop checks to catch `None` types, but it is not catching this one, although it does catch it in the first call.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: There are three statements that contain `curr.getNext()`, the while condition will only check one of them. Take a look at the `curr.getNext()` call in the for loop, that's where the error is ocurring.

Answer (score 0):

The error is triggered by the inner most `curr = curr.getNext()`. You perform those calls in a loop, but never check whether `curr` is `None`, i.e. whether you arrived at the end of the list. You *do* check this in the outer loop, but not during the iteration of the *inner* loop.

Anyway, this algorithm will not be bullet proof even if you correct that situation.

Let's say you search for "a", "b", "c" in a list that has "a", "a", "b", "c". This code (when your issue is corrected) will not find the match, because it will focus on the first "a", and the inner loop will move `curr` three positions ahead only to conclude there was no match. But at that time it has already missed the *good* starting point for a match, and will not find a match at all.

After a failing match, a brute force algorithm would have to come *back* to where it started that attempt, and continue from there in the main loop.

Also, you should exit the iteration over the data as soon as you find a mismatch. At that moment you already know the outcome, and continuing the inner loop is not going to change that.

Here is fix:

```
def bruteForce(aList, data):
    index = 0
    curr = aList.getHead()
    while curr.getNext() != None:
        temp = curr  # Use another reference for comparing with data
        for value in data:  # Get data values directly
            # Avoid error and check the list still has a node here
            if temp is None or temp.getData() != value:
                break  # Mismatch: No need to look further. 
            temp = temp.getNext()  # Don't move curr here
        else:  # when all of data matches
            return index  # Success!
        # ... continue with the original reference
        curr = curr.getNext()
        index += 1
    return -1  # Indication that there was no match
```

I would not print anything in the function. Let the caller of this function decide what to do:

- Return value is -1? Then report that there was no match
- Return value is >=0 ? Then report this value: it is the index where a match was found.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave some feed-back?